# When a sentence contains the word or, does that mean each sentence stands alone

Tags: syntactic-analysis

As used in this section,

> “medical evidence” means expert opinion or testimony stated to a reasonable degree of medical certainty, documents, records, **or** other material that is offered by a licensed and qualified medical physician.

My position is that there are two different ways to establish medical evidence.

The way preceding the OR and the way after the or.

This involves a Workers Compensation matter so I also ask if it has a different legal meaning.

Comment: You are listing four things: (1) opinion or testimony, (2) documents, (3) records, (4) other material. It's ambiguous if "offered by a physician" applies only to "other material" or if it applies to "document, records, or other material." Saying "the way preceding the OR and the way after the or" makes no sense. There is no interpretation in which *or* separates two things. For that to happen, you would need an *or* after *certainty* and to rephrase it to provide an explicit meaning. (The title of your question also doesn't make sense; there is only one sentence.)

Comment: The text of your ‘question’ doesn’t really ask a question, except for the WC matter (which doesn’t sound like a question about language). The rest is just a quote and some assertions. Please [edit] for clarity.

Comment: The section given does not establish "two ways".  Simply relying on a single "or" to clearly establish your position is not possible. I think you need to reword your example section, possibly into two or more sentences, that clearly state the two "ways" you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As a [coordinating conjunction](https://www.thoughtco.com/coordinating-conjunction-grammar-1689929), *or* joins two or more elements of equal syntactical importance and topicality. The first *or* joins two equivalent types of evidence usually offered orally by a witness; the second joins three nouns — documents, records, or other material — all of which must be offered by a licensed physician, i.e., things rather than speech. If none of these criteria are satisfied, then whatever evidence is offered may still be valid; it’s just not *medical* evidence by this definition.

There is no grammatical, semantic, or logical way you can divide this sentence by chopping it in half at the second *or*. I also fail to see how that could possibly be advantageous.

Answer (score 0):

Is this text something you are writing or is this text something you are trying to interpret (as in a legal document or the text of a law)?

As @JasonBassford mentioned, there is some ambiguity.  Does *medical evidence* mean one or more of four things or two?  That is, is it:

1. expert opinion or testimony (stated to a reasonable degree of medical
   certainty),
2. documents,
3. records, or
4. other material that is offered by a licensed and qualified medical physician.

or is it:

1. expert opinion or testimony (stated to a reasonable degree of medical certainty_,
2. documents, records, or other material (that is offered by a licensed and qualified medical physician).

I am not a lawyer (and this is not the [Law stack](https://law.stackexchange.com/)) nor am I a doctor but I would suggest that the intended meaning is the former -- that there are four types of medical evidence.  It seems to me that documents and records could both be provided by hospital staff/administrators or even by a government entity (birth and death certificates, for example.)  Other material, however, would need to be provided by a doctor.

This would, of course, be something that could be argued in court if one interpretation was more advantageous to one party than the other.  (If, perhaps, one party wants to use records provided by a non-physician -- a PA, RN, or doula, for example -- and the other party wants to disqualify them.)